# How to debug with android studio when my app is open?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set android studio to debug mode with while my app is opened and working, but i can't do it.

the app is already in bitbucket and is actually working for the company but it is doing something wrong about the data, so i need to debug it, how can i do it with the app itself and not with a copy of the code from bitbucket??

I opened the icons for debugging, i tried restarting the device, using the adb kill-server command in cmd, with Run / Edit Configurations and nothing seems to work, i need to debug in android studio while the app is opened and working.

how can i do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i do it on my end

1. First you need to identify where/or at least have a guess of what is wrong and how to reproduce it.
2. Second identify the classes involved to perform the task and put break points between the piece of code you want to debug.
3. Third, Run the app in debuggable mode from your android studio by clicking the little green bug icon close to the normal run icon
   4 Android studio should launch the android Monitor automatically but if not click on the Android Monitor tab located on the bottom of android studio.
4. Try to reproduce the problem, and your application will stop right on the break points, use the Android monitor tools to step-in and out of your code. Android studio displays outputs, therefore you can see if what you observe is the correct output, if not try to solve it first before moving forward. Sometimes the app will crash when it reaches the line with issues and thats how you start looking more into it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! i made it! android's monitor now displays all the things i do in the android device, like touching whatever position on the screen for example, but it only shows me functions that are being called as i go further in the android app and touch certains buttons and things like that, but, how can i see the code of the app when i'm like debugging? i was specting some kind of line color in the editor line by line till the error or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Attach debugger to Android process [image] . If your Application is already running, you could simply use this to attach debugger to your Application's Android process and start debugging.
2. Click on **Debug** [image] which will build and run your Application in debug mode.